# How to add a list of object in combobox C# WPF

Tags: c#, class, object, foreach, combobox

I wanna add to a combobox a list of object created in a form.
But for exemple, if I create 7 object, it will creates 7 object with the same name (the latest name created) in the combobox.
I don't know if it was clear but the code for add to the combobox is here :

```
    private void TabSupp_Famille(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CBFamilleSuppr.Items.Clear();
        foreach (Famille unPrenomMere in LesFamilles)
        {
            CBFamilleSuppr.Items.Add(uneFamille.GetNomMere()+" "+ uneFamille.GetPrenomMere());
        }
    }
```

for the class :
    public class Famille
    {
        private string NomMere;
        private string PrenomMere;
        private string NomPere;
        private string PrenomPere;
        private string TelPersoMere;
        private string TelTravailMere;
        private string TelPersoPere;
        private string TelTravailPere;

```
    public Famille(string unNomMere, string unPrenomMere, string unNomPere, string unPrenomPere, string unTelPersoMere, string unTelTravailMere, string unTelPersoPere, string unTelTravailPere)
    {
        NomMere = unNomMere;
        PrenomMere = unPrenomMere;
        NomPere = unNomPere;
        PrenomPere = unPrenomPere;
        TelPersoMere = unTelPersoMere;
        TelTravailMere = unTelTravailMere;
        TelPersoPere = unTelPersoPere;
        TelTravailPere = unTelTravailPere;
    }

    public string GetNomMere()
    {
        return (NomMere);
    }

    public string GetNomPere()
    {
        return (NomPere);
    }
    public string GetPrenomMere()
    {
        return (PrenomMere);
    }

    public string GetPrenomPere()
    {
        return (PrenomPere);
    }
    public string GetTelPersoMere()
    {
        return (TelPersoMere);
    }
    public string GetTelTravailMere()
    {
        return (TelTravailMere);
    }
    public string GetTelPersoPere()
    {
        return (TelPersoPere);
    }
    public string GetTelTravailPere()
    {
        return (TelTravailPere);
    }
}
```

and for create an object :

```
    private void btnaddfamille_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        uneFamille = new Famille(tbxNMere.Text, tbxPMere.Text, tbxNPere.Text, tbxPPere.Text, tbxTelPMere.Text, tbxTelTMere.Text, tbxTelPPere.Text, tbxTelTPere.Text);
        LesFamilles.Add(uneFamille);
        cbxfamille.Items.Add(uneFamille.GetNomMere() + " " + uneFamille.GetPrenomMere());
    }
```